# how to trigger a script on EC2 from HTTP request

Tags: http, heroku, web, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am building a web application (deployed on Heroku) where the user can upload a data file (e.g., a CSV or JSON file) and I have a script on my EC2 that will analyze the data file and store the results in a database (running on my EC2).

How do you create a "trigger" on the website to invoke the script? Specifically, a button would be pressed on the web application, and this would tell the EC2 to run the script using the uploaded data file as input.

Comment: Couldn't the server-side code responsible for the file upload also trigger your script once the upload is completed?

Comment: yes, but on the web app's upload page there is a button, that i have a javascript handler function for when the button is clicked by the user.